# True/false :If $ (Bx, x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n $, then $B =0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is following statement is True/false

> If $B \in M_n( \mathbb{C}))$ is such that $ (Bx, x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{C}^n $, then $B =0$

My attempt :I think NO ,  Every real matrix  is complex  so take $B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 \\-1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and  $x$ as  unit vector
then $(Bx,x)=0$

Is its true ?

Comment: Your example works in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but not in $\mathbb{C}^2$: some vectors are not orthogonal to their image. Indeed, if you take $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1\\i\end{array}\right)$, then $Bx = \left(\begin{array}{c}i\\-1\end{array}\right)$, and then $(Bx,x) = i(\overline{1})  -1(\overline{i}) = i+i=2i\neq 0$.  The result actually holds over the complex numbers.

Comment: It might be also worthy to mention that the dot products for real and complex numbers behaves differently: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example $(Bx,x)=0$ only for real vectors $x$.

The result is true. Hints for a proof: $(B(x+iy),(x+iy))=0$ and $(B(x-iy),(x-iy))=0$. Expand these and show that $(Bx,y)=0$ for all $x,y$. That will sow that $B=0$.

Remark: The inner product of $a+ib$ and $c+id$ ($a,b,c,d$ real) is not $ac+bd$; it is $ac-bd$.

Comment: in remark portion  i think $ac -  bd$ @ kavi sir

Comment: @jasmine Right. That was  a typo.